# How to access single fields of an embedded object array with a dynamic variable (Meteor)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, meteor

I have an array of strings with a length which has been defined by the user.

```
pickedStrings = ["A", "B", "G", "L", "Y"];
```

Could also be :

```
pickedStrings = ["A", "G"] or pickedStrings  = ["A", "L", "Y"]
```

or any other combination. There can also be more possible strings in the future.

With these strings I can identify several objects in a mongo document by looping through that array and query my objects.

```
var pickedArray, fLen, pickedDataArray, i;

pickedArray = pickedStrings;
fLen = pickedStrings.length;
pickedDataArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {

var item = pickedArray[i];

var values = valueCollection.findOne({'_id': "myDoc"}, {fields: {[item]:1 , '_id':0}});
console.log(values);

pickedDataArray.push(values);

}

console.log(pickedDataArray);
```

The `console.log(pickedDataArray);` returns only the objects I want (the ones specified by, for example, `pickedStrings = ["A", "B"];`:

```
[
     { A:
          { GP: 37.56,
            ES: 67.51,
            EV: 12.12,
            CR: 45.90,
            Data: [Object] 
           } 
      },
      { B:
          { GP: 7.62,
            ES: 7.51,
            EV: 22.82,
            CR: 75.40,
            Data: [Object] 
           } 
       } 
]
```

This works fine. However, now I need to get only the single fields e.g. GP per object from the query (`pickedDataArray`) and save them in a new array. So in this case I need the output:

```
neededArray = [37.56, 7.62]
```

I have two problems I cannot solve. The first one is that I don´t know how to filter or find only one field from this **embedded** object array.
I tried this, but this does not work and produces a array with undefined values:

```
var neededArray = pickedDataArray.map(a => a.A.GP);
```

My second problem is, that the identifier "A" and "B" or any other string the user defines is a dynamic variable right? So do I have to write a loop again with `var item = pickedArray[i];` ?

I am using the Meteor framework with MongoDB.

Comment: I see several wrong things here. First, Mongo calls are asynchronous, but you wrote them like synchronous code, in a `for` loop, and followed by `console.log`. This can just not work. Since it's asynchronous, you will only get your data in the callback, not on the following line. Then, `"myDoc"` is a totally invalid Mongo _id, and it will throw for sure `Failed to cast value "myDoc" to ObjectId`. IMO this can just not work at all for both reasons.

Comment: Well, I don’t know exactly what you mean, but I am using Meteor and this written in a Server side Meteor Method Call and this is actually the code I have and it works until the output in the Meteor Console. Sorry, I should have mentioned that before if this is imporant..

Comment: Ah, it may be important indeed, because I have absolutely no experience with Meteor :) So maybe it makes the above code work with some black magic, but I have no idea how.

Comment: On server side as far as I know with meteor these calls works as "synchronous" (I say as synchronous because it's something like they are wrapper to be syncrhonous like, therefor it works without optimizing the ressources), working on a reply for you

Answer (score 0):

I got your needed result like this, but it works only if pickedStrings and pickedDataArray are the same length and in the same order (which should be the case) or otherwise a sorting is needed.

```
let neededArray = [];

const neededField = 'GP';
for (let i = 0; i < pickedStrings.length; i++ {
   neededArray.push(pickedDataArray[i][pickedStrings[i]][neededField])
}
console.log(neededArray)
```